# Edit default main.cpp file in CLion

Tags: c++, clion, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to edit default main.cpp file in CLion? Because when I create a new project I need prepared main.cpp file. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the current version [EAP 143.249.8], this doesn't seem to be possible.

I suggest that you request this feature [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP).